# how do you reference this html object in javascript? applescript

Tags: javascript, html, applescript, javascript-framework

I want to reference these two buttons, but am unsure how to reference them to click them.

I found this statement:

do JavaScript `document.forms[0]['btnI'].click()` in front document

and want to change it reference this:

```
<li id="app_114228431971868" class="114228431971868">
  <div>
    <img class="gameimg" src="http://photos-g.ak.fbcdn.net/photos-ak-snc1/v27562/200/114228431971868/app_1_114228431971868_5955.gif" width="75" height="75">
   </div>
   <p>Knights of the Crystals</p>
</li>
```

Then I want to add a second command to press this button:

```
<div id="get-button"></div>
```

Then a third to reference this button:

```
<img width="125" height="50" alt="Ready!" src="http://gffstatic.oneringgame.com/images/btn-ready.png" id="ggg-readybut" style="display: inline; ">
```

I think you put the id where the btnI is in the javascript, but am unsure what to do for the other parts of the line.

Comment: What does this have to do with applescript?

Comment: Looks like he is injecting the Javascript via Applescript.

Comment: I want to use this inside applescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reference a DOM element by ID:

```
document.getElementById("theid");
```

So:

```
document.getElementById("get-button").click()
```

And:

```
document.getElementById("ggg-readybut") //reference to the image element
```

Comment: thank you for your help. yet I'm still having problems. I'm getting an error of using this inside applescript. It says it is "expecting end of line, ect, but found identifier."

Comment: here is what I have so far

 `open location "http://apps.facebook.com/gfriendfinder/?ref=bookmarks&count=0"`       

 `delay 5`

 `activate application "Safari"`

 
 
 
 `do JavaScript "document.getElementById("app_114228431971868");"`

 `do JavaScript "document.getElementById("app_114228431971868").click()"`

Comment: @user That error usually means that there's a problem with the quotation marks in your code. Be sure to put a \ in front of any quotation marks inside the main ones: `do javascript "document.getElementByID(\"theID\").click()"`

Comment: Either that or use `'` instead of `"` inside the javascript. Always glad to help!

Answer (score -1):

```
open location "http://apps.facebook.com/gfriendfinder/?ref=bookmarks&count=0"
delay 5
activate application "Safari"



do JavaScript "document.getElementById("app_114228431971868");"
do JavaScript "document.getElementById("app_114228431971868").click()"
```

Comment: You need to escape the internal quote marks: `do JavaScript "document.getElementById(\"app_114228431971868\");"